# How to stabilize Random Per Island for Meta Objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, meta-objects

I have a very basic AN setup where I vector jiggle the position of meta ball instances for a lava-lamp-like motion.

I wanted to change the color as soon as an individual Meta Ball disconnects from another and tried to do that via the `Geometry` --> `Random per Island node`.
That works pretty well on a single frame but as the mesh is recalculated/reevaluated every frame, the random number output changes on every frame for every island. So the colors change constantly.

I’m looking for a solution, where the color only changes, as soon as a meta object disconnects. Any ideas?

*(I don’t think I need to add any screenshots of my setup, as my problem is expected behaviour.)*

Comment: I'm very interested. There is something fishy here. It not only changes with every frame, but it also changes : when you move the original mball object, all islands are re-calculated at each depsgraph update. When you move another mball, it recalculates itself every time, but it doesn't recalculate other islands if they are at a lower X OR a lower Y OR a lower Z. It also seems when it reaches a certain threshold, it affects the other islands again. It is very inconsistent

Comment: Thats very interesting indeed. I just thought: Well OK, it just recalculates EVERYTHING if one ball from the same family changes. (in my case, every object was moving, so it changed anyways)